# Безопасность кода на Си

Tags: c

С точки зрения безопасности, насколько этот код безопасен и правилен?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "file.h"

long
getFileSize(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!fp)
        return -1L;

    if (!fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END)) {
        fclose(fp);

        return -1L;
    }

    long fileSize = ftell(fp);

    if (fileSize == -1L) {
        fclose(fp);

        return -1L;
    }

    if (!fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET)) {
        fclose(fp);

        return -1;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return fileSize;
}

char *
getFileContents(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!fp)
        return NULL;

    long fileSize = getFileSize(fileName);

    if (fileSize == -1L) {
        fclose(fp);

        return NULL;
    }

    char *fileContents = calloc(fileSize + 1, sizeof(char));

    if (fileContents) {
        fclose(fp);

        return NULL;
    }

    if (fread(fileContents, sizeof(char), fileSize, fp) != fileSize) {
        free(fileContents);
        fclose(fp);

        return NULL;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return fileContents;
}
```

Comment: и стоит ли проверять функцию fclose на возвращаемое значение?

Comment: Как минимум вы пытаетесь открыть уже открытый файл, что в принципе как минимум лишнее...

Comment: @Harry в двух функциях отдельное открытие, я подумал, что так будет лучше и без лишних заморочек, но вопрос в другом

Comment: `if (!fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END)) {
        fclose(fp);` при успехе `fseek` вернет 0, и вы тут же закроете файл и вернете -1...

Comment: `if (fileContents) {` - забыли `!`

Comment: да дело не в этом, вопрос заключается в том, стоит ли проверят каждую функцию или нет?

Comment: Если результат, возвращаемый функцией влияет на дальнейший ход алгоритма, то нужно проверять. Если же нет, как со всеми `fclose()` у вас (поскольку файл открывается на чтение), то не стоит. Кстати, зачем вызывать `calloc` (неужели из-за одного последнего байта)?

Comment: @user339847: Если "вопрос в другом", то почему это не указано в вопросе?

Comment: Можно еще проверить, что `fileName` — не `NULL`: `assert(fileName != NULL)`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Во всех функциях параметр `fileName` имеет смысл сделать `const char *`.
2. Позиционирование `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END)` может не поддерживаться вообще. А если и поддерживается, то только для *бинарных* потоков. Поэтому в функции `getFileSize` открывать ваш файл вам нужно в бинарном режиме `"rb"`. Это же касается и `getFileContents`.
3. Функция `fseek` возвращает `0` при *успешном* позиционировании. У вас все условия проверки успешности `fseek` записаны "наоборот".
4. И здесь тоже условие успешности записано "наоборот"

   ```
   char *fileContents = calloc(fileSize + 1, sizeof(char));

   if (fileContents) { // <-- ???
       fclose(fp);
       return NULL;
   }
   ```
5. Какой смысл вы вкладываете в `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET)` перед закрытием файла в `getFileSize`? Зачем вы это делаете?
6. В функции `getFileContents` определение размера файла (вызов `getFileSize`) можно было выполнить *до* открытия файла. Зачем плодить лишние уровни открытия (одного и того же) файла? И зачем создавать лишнюю заботу о `fclose(fp)` при возникновении ошибки?
7. Почему памяти выделяется на `+1` больше, чем размер файла? Вы хотите получить нуль-терминированную строку в результате? Это что-ли текстовый файл?
8. Избыточная типизация констант суффиксом `L` - зачем?

Comment: Если это *не текстовый* файл, то работать с таким API не получится (размер файла не передается caller-у)